# scipy.fftpack's FFT freezing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, fftpack

When computing a FFT of an array of size ~ 1.5 million items:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft

x0 = np.ones(1492828, dtype=np.int32)
fft(x0)
print 'hello'
```

the FFT computation never finishes, and the program is freezing. If I change `1492828` to `1492827`, it seems to work. But if I change `1492828` to `1492826`, it still freezes, which is kind of strange.

Is this a known bug?

Note:

- The CPU stays at 25% (normal, I have a 4-core CPU), and the RAM usage of the Python process stays at ~75 MB
- I'm using Python 2.7.15 64-bit on Windows 7 64-bit:

  ```
  print scipy.__version__     # 1.1.0
  print sys.version           # 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
  ```

Comment: Have you tried [`np.fft.fft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html)?

Comment: @Brenlla in the past yes, but for this project, I have coded everything with `scipy.fftpack.fft` so I wanted to see if this is a known bug before moving to `np.fft.fft`. Can you reproduce the error too?

Comment: This is not a bug. Depending on the implementation, the FFT algorithm performs good for composite lengths (products of powers of small primes). [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357589/numpy-fft-is-fast-for-lengths-that-are-products-of-small-primes-but-how-small) for additional information. The prime factors of 1492828 are 2 and **373207**, while for 1492827 they are much smaller (3, 7, 67, 1061), and for 1492826 they are big again...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strange numpy fft performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161033/strange-numpy-fft-performance)

Comment: @kazemakase it's not only about performance, it's about the fact it sometimes doesn't return at all and freezes (more than 3 minutes...)

Comment: Yep, same problem in my computer with both `np` and `sp` fft versions

Comment: @Basj of course it is about performance. You're just not patient enough to wait for it to finish ;) Joking aside, n=1492828 is really, really horrible for FFT. I would not be surprides if it took hours to complete.

Comment: @kazemakase Oh ok ;) btw, is there a short `numpy` way to zero-pad an array to the next power of 2?

Comment: Sure there is. Here is a somewhat unwieldy one-liner: `np.concatenate([x, np.zeros(int(2**np.ceil(np.log2(len(x))))-len(x))])`. Powers of 2 can be wasteful (there are not many of those among large numbers). Any product of powers of small primes may work well, but it would make the padding more complex.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kazemakase! Could you post it as an answer (or I can do it for you prefer)? (None of the answers in the nearly-duplicate mention this). Another thing: does this concatenation preserve original `dtype`?

Comment: @Basj no, to preserve the type you'd need to pass `dtype=x.dtype` to `np.zeros`.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer - comments are fair game as they say ;) (But I would not be surprised if some deeper digging would reveal that answer too on the site - or a better one.)

Answer (score 3):

The usual FFT algorithms are much faster for length having small prime factors, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21161146/1422096).

The solution is to zero-pad the array to the next power of 2:

```
def zeropad_nextpoweroftwo(A):
    return np.concatenate([A, np.zeros(int(2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(len(A))))-len(A), 
        dtype=A.dtype)])
```

Or, an even easier/nicer solution is to use [`next_fast_len`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len.html) and the fact that the 2nd argument of [`fftpack.fft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html#scipy.fftpack.fft) allows to do zero-padding automatically:

```
fftpack.fft(a, next_fast_len(len(a)))
```

Comment: Instead of padding to the next power of 2, one can pad to the next [5-smooth number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) by using [`scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len.html).

Comment: You might as well update your answer.  I suspect the question is more-or-less a duplicate--the same problem is rediscovered every now and then--but I haven't searched.